# Max Voltage of Electrical Stimulator for Cardiac Tissue Bioreactor

Tags: voltage, batteries, resistance

I'm designing a bioreactor that will electrically and mechanically stimulate cells in media in an incubator. I'm using monophasic, square waveforms and have a max stimulation level of 12V/cm, else they don't respond. I bought an electrical stimulator powered by a 9V battery and listed in the manual is a peak amplitude of 105 miliAmps at 1000Ohms. When measuring with a voltmeter from one electrode to the other, without touching the electrode, the solution has a resistance of 1900 Ohms.

Will the max voltage drop across the resistor be 9v, assuming the wires are perfect conductors? And with the stimulator, you can alter the current, but not the voltage, so what should I set the current at?

Once again, this will never be tested on humans, so I'm not super worried about messing up, I just don't want to make any huge errors as this is a design project and I've only taken one class for electrical enigneering, being that I'm a bioengineering student.

I thought I could just multiply optimum stimulation level

Thanks for any help and let me know if you need any more info...

Comment: "the max voltage drop across the resistor" - what resistor? Can you give us a schematic? A datasheet for your stimulator might also be helpful (although it sounds like you've gotten the most important details) - what is this, exactly? Is it a fancy signal generator?

Comment: If you need 12 V/cm and you have 9 V, sounds like the electrodes can only be 7 mm apart. But your stimulator says 0.1 A into 1000 Ohms, which requires 100 V. Not likely it can generate that much power from a 9 V battery, unless the pulses are very short. Can you clarify a bit more: what V do you need, or what V/m? What does the generator claim to produce?

Comment: Also, 100 V at 100 mA could be lethal if you hold both leads, even if it is only powered by a small battery. So be careful with this generator, keep one hand behind your back when touching any wires.

Comment: You should post a part number/link for the stimulator

Answer (score 1):

Your stimulator is a constant-current device, which means it will vary voltage automatically in order to keep the current at a set value. The maximal voltage it can achieve depends entirely on the internal design -- if it really claims 105 milliamps into 1000 ohm load, this means it can output up 100 volts, which means it must have some sort of voltage step-up circuit inside.

If your resistance will be constant, then you set the current using Ohm's law: current = voltage / resistance, for example for 12 volts and 1900 ohms, you set 6.3 milliamperes. The only problem is that if resistance changes (for example due to changed concentration of ions), so will voltage. For the previous case, if your media has less ions and resistance is now 950 ohms, the stimulator will now output 24 volts to try and maintain the same 6.3 milliamperes current. Thus, if you really care about fixed voltage, get a stimulator where you can set the voltage directly.